# ExecutorService invokeAll deadlock

Tags: java-7, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

While writing a skeleton program for `ExecutorService invokeAll` I came across an interesting scenario which seems created a deadlock. Couldn't figure out exactly why this is happening.

Here is the program which instantiates 3 tasks and calls `invokeAll()`

```
        int poolSize = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        Set<Callable<Object>> tasksSet = new HashSet<>();
        tasksSet.add(new Task1());
        tasksSet.add(new Task2());
        tasksSet.add(new Task3());

        List<Future<Object>> resultSet = pool.invokeAll(tasksSet);
        for (Future<Object> future : resultSet) {
            Object result;
            try {
                   result = future.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Logger.getLogger(CallableDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        pool.shutdown();
```

And `Task1` code:

```
public class Task1 implements Callable<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        long val = 0;
        for (long i = 0; i < Long.MAX_VALUE - 5000; i++) {
            val += i;
        }
        return "Sucessfull Task1 object...";
    }

}
```

`Task2` and `Task3` code also same except these two classes use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` in for loop check.

When I run this program it stuck forever and interestingly other two tasks also didn't run. My machine has is 8-core processor. Any thoughts why this behavior?

If I change Long.MAX_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE, everything works fine.

Another interesting observation is:

Instead of calling `invokeAll()`, if `submit()` these tasks individually, two other tasks completed on time except Task1 (which has Long.MAX_VALUE).

Comment: any chance you got a thread dump for your program? That would be the best way to determine if there is actually a deadlock.

Comment: It is always reproducible, so getting thread dump may not be an issue. But what I am struggling here is, on machine with multicore, shouldn't the task handling be concurrent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior you observe is indeed the expected one. Consider the following:

1) Task3 counts up to Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5000, whereas Task1 and Task2 count up to Long.MAX_VALUE - 5000. All things being equal, this means that Task1 and Task2 will last 2^32 times longer than Task3, that's over *4 billion times longer*.

2) As specified in the Javadoc for [AbstractExecutorService.invokeAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) (emphasis mine):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their
>   status and results **when all complete**.

So, what is happening is that Task3 completes very quickly, but the other two tasks will run for days or more likely for months. Since `invokeAll()` only returns once *all tasks* have completed, you effectively never see it return.

You can easily verify this by printing a trace in Task3 right after the `for` loop, for instance:

```
public static class Task3 implements Callable<Object> {
  @Override
  public Object call() throws Exception {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    long val = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE - 5000; i++) {
      val += 1;
    }
    double elapsed = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000d;
    System.out.printf("Task3 terminated in %.3f ms%n", elapsed);
    return "Sucessfull Task3 object...";
  }
}
```

On my 8-core machine, it gives me: `Task3 terminated in 568.938 ms`. To give an idea, even if Task3 were to complete in only 1 ms, it would still take over 46 days for the other two tasks to complete.

On a side note, I'm not sure what you wanted to accomplish with `val += i` in your `for` loop, since this will result in many integer overflows.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I over looked "when all complete" in documentation, which forced me to think it is unexpected behaviour. Now it makes sense. This is dummy program, val +=i etc., are just there, no importance.